# The Windows Remote Desktop auto-type mess with KeePass

Tags: windows-10, remote-desktop, keepass

Well, being confronted with a "secure environment" where any reasonable work has to be done using Windows accessible from Windows via Remote Desktop (also using different accounts in different Active Directories), I have some password trouble (thanks to the great concepts from Microsoft):

- For a normal login, it seems I can paste the password via clipboard
- If pasting via clipboard does not work, I can use auto-type
- sometimes (but not always) pasting from the clipboard works if Remote Desktop is not in full-screen mode

The real fun begins, when it's about to change your secure password:

- You cannot paste your existing password into the password field; you must use auto-type (or manual typing) instead
- The sequence of steps is different, depending on whether the password has not expired yet, or must be changed, because it has expired
- Whatever mode the Remote Desktop session is, the windows title never changes.  Specifically that means you cannot decide programmatically whether your password change was successful, or not.

Sometimes the user field is pre-filled, sometimes it is not (e.g. login vs. lock screen)

So I ended up with a set of auto-type sequences:

- Plain login: `{PASSWORD}`
- Lock screen: `{CLEARFIELD}{UserName}{TAB}{PASSWORD}`
- Change non-expired password: `{CLEARFIELD}{Password}{TAB}{NEWPASSWORD}{TAB}{NEWPASSWORD}{ENTER}`
- Change expired password: `{CLEARFIELD}{UserName}{TAB}{Password}{ENTER}{DELAY 1000}{ENTER}{NEWPASSWORD}{TAB}{NEWPASSWORD}{ENTER}`

As pointed out, the window title matching cannot be used, so I have to move the rules up and down before use as needed.
When the wrong rule is applied (e.g. running the password change) the password may be over-written.
Similarly when a password change was attempted, but failed (KeePass replaces the password with a new one, thinking the password change was successful).

Are there any better solutions?

Answer (score 1):

I always use the setting "Always show global auto-type entry selection dialog".
This way it always show me all options there is for this window, and I can select between them.
I know just a "workaround", but it helped me a lot of times.